# Vncserver not connect /.vnc/xstartup: 13: gnome-settings-daemon: not found in EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, gnome, ubuntu-22.04, vnc-server, tightvnc

I am trying to add GUI to my Ubuntu 22.04 EC2 instance.
I was following this guide [here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/ubuntu-desktop-aws#3-configuring-the-vnc-server).

When I run

```
vncserver :1
```

I get this error

```
New Xtigervnc server 'i- xxxxx.ec2.internal:1 (xxxx)' on port 5901 for display :1.
Use xtigervncviewer -SecurityTypes VncAuth -passwd /home/xxxx/.vnc/passwd :1 to connect to the VNC server.


=================== tail /home/xxxx/.vnc/i-xxxxxxxxcc.ec2.internal:5901.log ===================
/home/xxxx/.vnc/xstartup: 13: gnome-settings-daemon: not found
=======================================================================================================

Session startup via '/home/xxxxx/.vnc/xstartup' cleanly exited too early (< 3 seconds)!

Maybe try something simple first, e.g.,
    tigervncserver -xstartup /usr/bin/xterm
The X session cleanly exited!
Killing Xtigervnc process ID 446984... success!
```

if this helps I ssh into my EC2 using this command

```
ssh -i publickey user@ip -p 1022
```

I don't have access to the EC2 instance but a custom TCP port 5091 has been added in Inbound rules as stated [here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/ubuntu-desktop-aws#4-aws-configuration).

Thanks for your help